# Get data from controller to Component AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components, angularjs-components

I have a problem. I create a component in AngularJs and I want to pass data from controller to Component.

Data comes to template component, but in the controller on component is undefined!

This is my code.

The controller

```
angular.module('testModule')
.controller('testController', ['$scope',
    function($scope){
        var vm = this;
        vm.name = "John";
    }
]);
```

The component. Here in the **console.log(vm.name)** its undefined! This is my problem.

```
angular.module('testModule')
    .component('testComponent', {
        bindings: {
            "name": '='
        },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            var vm = this;
            console.log(vm);              
            console.log(vm.name);
        }],
        template: "<h2>Hi {{ctrl.name}}</h2>",
    });
```

HTML

```
<html ng-app="testModule">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="testController.js"></script>
    <script src="testComponent.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="testController as ctrl">
    <test-component name="ctrl.name"></test-component>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/JS10zDUH6ZCSHWpLbQOE?p=preview)

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be hooking up over `$onInit` method to see what component `bindings` has.

```
vm.$onInit = function(){
    console.log(vm.name);
}
```

---

The things which you were trying to do was totally doable till angular 1.5.X, but since AngularJS 1.6+ version they disabled prepopulating context of controller by introducing `preAssignBindingsEnabled` over `$compileProvider`. By default it is set to false. If you really want to see this working you could try to set the flag by below code(but I'd not recommend to use this). The main reason behind introducing this change is to make Angular and AngularJS API to look similar by design & architecture, eventually it will make one step closer to migration to Angular.

```
.config(function($compileProvider){
  $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);
})
```

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/A54UsXUWSeu1K1MbZoEG?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Regards